# In magento how to format date in email template?

Tags: email, frontend

In magento how to format date in email template ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to override core file  `/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`,

```
public function getCreatedAtFormatedHideTime($format)
{
    return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), $format, false);
}
```

You can call it in Email template :

`{{var order.getCreatedAtFormatedHideTime('short')}}`

Output:

10/10/2015

Comment: This answer doesn't seem belonging to the question. What does email date formatting has to do with order?

Comment: It's just an example of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To format a date in Magento you can use

```
$dateToFormat = '2011-12-11';
Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($dateToFormat, 'medium', false);
```

Unfortunately you can't directly use PHP in email templates, so you have to insert a block `{{block type="core/template" template="your/template/file.php"}}`

and in this template you are free to use PHP.

Comment: I like this better than having to override a core file.